# Can logrotate automatically track the size of the log file and rotate it when its size exceeds the limit?

Tags: linux, logrotate

I saw the `size` directive and created the configuration file /etc/logrotate.d/test:

```
/home/user/log1 {
    size 100
    rotate 3
    compress
}
```

but it doesn't work as I expect. The file should be rotated when its size becomes more than 100 bytes, and this does not happen. Nothing happens when the file size exceeds the limit, the file is not rotated, a new archive with the old log1 file is not created

Is it possible to achieve this behavior with logrotate?

OS is ubuntu 20

Comment: The rotation will happen when logrotate runs, and that's probably once a day or so by default in most distros. You might want to try something like https://github.com/jbaublitz/logrustate (based on Google results for a logrotate that can "watch" for things, never tried it myself)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What exactly means "it doesn't work as I expect"? You wrote what you expect, but not what actually happens. Does it rotate the logfile at all? What size do the rotated files have? At what date/time did the rotation take place?

Comment: please provide your OS release info as well

Comment: `logrotate` is not a daemon that runs in the background and is able to react when the file grows. It's a program run from cron, anacron or systemd, usually once a day. To see if your config works, you need to wait until `logrotate` runs; or you need to start it manually, it will do its job and will exit.